# Vapor registered 'ToDo' database yet PostgreSQL doesn't show it from the prompt

Tags: vapor, vapor-fluent

**Environment:** Vapor v4.77 
**Database:** Postgresql@15 via Homebrew

Here's the environment:

```
/Users/Ric> echo $DATABASE_NAME
ToDo
/Users/Ric> echo $DATABASE_HOST
localhost
/Users/Ric> echo $DATABASE_PORT
5432
```

Here's the **Configuraton**:

```
public func configure(_ app: Application) async throws {
    // uncomment to serve files from /Public folder
    // app.middleware.use(FileMiddleware(publicDirectory: app.directory.publicDirectory))

    app.databases.use(DatabaseConfigurationFactory.postgres(configuration: .init(
        hostname: Environment.get("DATABASE_HOST") ?? "localhost",
        port: Environment.get("DATABASE_PORT").flatMap(Int.init(_:)) ?? SQLPostgresConfiguration.ianaPortNumber,
        username: Environment.get("DATABASE_USERNAME") ?? "vapor_username",
        password: Environment.get("DATABASE_PASSWORD") ?? "vapor_password",
        database: Environment.get("DATABASE_NAME") ?? "vapor_database",
        tls: .prefer(try .init(configuration: .clientDefault)))
    ), as: .psql)

    // Migrations:
    app.migrations.add(CreateTodo())
    try await app.autoMigrate().get()

    // register routes
    try routes(app)
```

Here's the **migration**: 
{Temporally changed from 'name' to 'first_name', etc.}

```
import Fluent

struct CreateTodo: AsyncMigration {
    func prepare(on database: Database) async throws {
        try await database.schema("todos")
            .deleteField("title")
            .field("first_name", .string)
            .field("last_name", .string)
            .update()
    }

    func revert(on database: Database) async throws {
        try await database.schema("todos").delete()
    }
}
```

I've checked PostgreSQL via command problem and am unable to find the **Todo** database:

[image]

I'm able to do a **post** and **get** to prove there's persistent data.  But I can't find the database via the prompt.

I tried a using an existing database name, 'Turkey' (see above):

```
app.databases.use(DatabaseConfigurationFactory.postgres(configuration: .init(
        hostname: Environment.get("DATABASE_HOST") ?? "localhost",
        port: Environment.get("DATABASE_PORT").flatMap(Int.init(_:)) ?? SQLPostgresConfiguration.ianaPortNumber,
        username: Environment.get("DATABASE_USERNAME") ?? "vapor_username",
        password: Environment.get("DATABASE_PASSWORD") ?? "vapor_password",
//        database: Environment.get("DATABASE_NAME") ?? "vapor_database",
        database: "Turkey",
        tls: .prefer(try .init(configuration: .clientDefault)))
    ), as: .psql)
```

... and changed other db references to 'Turkey'.

Here's what I got after doing a >**swift run**:

[image]

Explanation?

Comment: Are you using the same Postgres user credentials from command line?

Comment: Yes.   I even checked to see if there are any other servers running in parallel.    There's only the one.  Vapor complains when the one server if off-line.   So it's it.   The data is persistent, yet it doesn't show up in the psql prompt @ MacOS.   Weird.

Comment: I don’t think this is a vapor-related problem.  You might get more help tagging Postgres.

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint when you configure the database and double checked the environment variables are being passed thorough correctly? Because it looks like they aren't

Comment: I added breakpoints and checked variables.   The vapor side appears to be okay.   The Postgre side is perhaps the problem.

Vapor depends on an active Postgre session.   And there is only ONE (1) session.  But it doesn't show the Todo database as created from Vapor, and Vapor can not access 'existing' databases within Postgre.  Yet there's data persistence.   So, I'm focussing on Postgre.   I can only continue with vapor development with autonomous access to the data via the outside (posture).   Eventually, I'll play with other database engines to see if I have the same problems.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got this to work. 
My problem was a combination of corrupt vapor code and case spelling.

**Solution:** 
1) Rollback code from the repository; 
2) Use a global constant to declare the database name lowercase per Postgres wish.  This reduces case mismatching hassles.